# Execution blocked by IOLoop.instance.start() in Tornado framework

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm trying to make a non-blocking TCP server using Tornado.

So I have subclassed `TCPServer` as stated in the [API](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html) and implemented `handle_stream`

But when the execution reach `IOLoop.current().start()` does not proceed more.
In all the example I have seen this is how the `TCPServer` works.

I think that I don't understand fully this technology. What am I missing? Why `IOLoop.instance().stop()` is never reached?

```
import logging
import tornado

from tornado import gen
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.netutil import bind_sockets

class CashDeskTCPServer(TCPServer):

    @gen.coroutine
    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        self._stream = stream
        self._read_line()

    @gen.coroutine
    def _read_line(self):
        self._stream.read_until('\n', self._handle_read)

    @gen.coroutine
    def _handle_read(self, data):
        self._stream.write(data)
        self._read_line()


if __name__ == '__main__': 

    sockets = bind_sockets(8889)
    tornado.process.fork_processes(0)
    server = CashDeskTCPServer()
    server.add_sockets(sockets)
    IOLoop.instance().start()

    IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado's [doc](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.start):

> The loop will run until one of the callbacks calls stop(), which will
>   make the loop stop after the current event iteration completes.

In other words - IOLoop's start is blocking, while it runs. The next statements will be executed if the loop stops. Moreover stopping ioloop, means stop listening (accepting new connections).

But since you using fork_processes(0) you might want to run ioloop on all process except one (parent - let's say master)

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    sockets = bind_sockets(8889)
    tornado.process.fork_processes(0)
    server = CashDeskTCPServer()
    server.add_sockets(sockets)
    # if you have 1 core there is no forks, so no ioloop will start
    if tornado.process.task_id() != 0:
        IOLoop.instance().start()
    else:
        print('Master process didn't start IOLoop')
```

Comment: And if I don't want to use `fork_processes`? Should I use `yield` inside a `coroutine`?